# Execute multiple queries

Tags: c#, sql, oledb, oledbcommand

I am using OleDB for executing my queries in C#,

Is there any way I can execute multiple queries in one command statement?

I tried to separate them with semi-colon (;) but it gives error "Characters found at the end"

I have to execute a few hundreds of queries at once.

Edit: I am executing Insert Statements.

Comment: The related question is basically for stored procedures. Didn't helped.

Comment: Well written question.  I expected it to me a nightmare trying to google for this specific problem, but there it was as the first result. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to combine queries within one [`OleDbCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand(VS.71).aspx). If possible, make a stored procedure, otherwise you'll have to stick to firing many OleDbCommands at the server.

It's worth noting, though, that connection pooling is enabled for [`OleDbConnection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx) by default:

> When you use the .NET Framework Data
>   Provider for OLE DB, you do not have
>   to enable connection pooling because
>   the provider manages this
>   automatically.

***EDIT:***

Try something like this:

```
INSERT INTO myTable ( Column1, Column2, Column3 )
SELECT 'Value1', 1, 'Value3'
UNION
SELECT 'Value1', 2, 'Value3'
UNION
SELECT 'Value1', 3, 'Value3'
UNION
SELECT 'Value1', 4, 'Value3'
```

Depending on which OleDb provider you're connecting to, you might be able to use this. But beware, it might be as slow as inserting records one by one anyway.

Comment: Example SQL does not work with Access database: *"Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression"* (Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0)

Answer (score 1):

Simply Batch them up using GO (groups a batch) and colons to separate queries inside a batch. Make sure to surround your colon with spaces. You need to submit this SQL to sp_executesql.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
GO
USE AdventureWorks;
GO
CREATE TABLE dbo.mycompanies
(
 id_num int IDENTITY(100, 5),
 company_name nvarchar(100)
)
GO
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'A Bike Store');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Progressive Sports');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Modular Cycle Systems');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Advanced Bike Components');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Metropolitan Sports Supply');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Aerobic Exercise Company');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Associated Bikes');
INSERT mycompanies (company_name)
   VALUES (N'Exemplary Cycles');
GO

SELECT id_num, company_name
FROM dbo.mycompanies
ORDER BY company_name ASC;
GO
COMMIT;
GO
```

Example taken from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191136.aspx).

Comment: `GO` only applies to Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. It is used to break statements up, and hence will not work when using `OleDbCommand`

Comment: GO can be used when executing your statement via sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

Use `sp_executesql`.

Do see [my answer in another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696565/deleting-records-from-multiple-tables-at-a-time-with-a-single-query-in-sqlserver2/2696699#2696699) where I include a sample usage of `sp_executesql` to send SQL queries in a batch.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to execute multiple SQL statements in an Access database using `OleDB` for a project I'm working on, and I couldn't find anything that's good enough for my situation, so I came up with this solution which basically breaks down the SQL string into multiple SQL statements and executes them in one transaction:

```
string sql = GetMultiStatementSqlString();
string[] sqlStatements = sql.Split(new[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connStr))
{
    conn.Open();
    OleDbTransaction transaction = conn.BeginTransaction();
    foreach (string statement in sqlStatements)
    {
        using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(statement, conn, transaction))
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Hope it helps someone.