# deleting rows from multiple tables at a time with a single query in sqlserver2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I wanna delete two rows from two tables which are foreign key related how can i delete the two rows from that two tables at a time using the single delete statement. Can any body help me by just posting some example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look: [deleting records from multiple tables at a time with a single query in sqlserver2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2696565/deleting-records-from-multiple-tables-at-a-time-with-a-single-query-in-sqlserver2)

Comment: i have seen that but it is not helping me

Comment: @Febin - that is because there is no way that I know of to do what you want with a *single* delete statement. A delete can only delete from *one* table (forgetting cascading deletes/triggers and the like).